# Update table if rows already exists while inserting if row does not exists from a dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure where I am inserting into a table from a SELECT statement. The table has 4 columns (e.g. Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4). Column1 has a unique value. and Column4 is the timestamp of when the rows are inserted.

[image: How table looks like in the first run (e.g. SP executed on teh 14032017).]
What I want to achieve is this:-

1.) That when I run the stored procedure on a later date lets say on the 20032017 I add the rows to the table if Col1 does not exists in the table.

2.) If Col1 already exists in the table I update the values of Col2 and Col3 while keeping tha value of Col5 as is.

So assuming in the second run of the stored procedure the select statement returns this dataset.
[image: The dataset returned from the SELECT statement in a second run.] 
The table will show like this,
Rows with Col1 value of 7 is inserted in the table.
Rows with Col1 values of 1, 2, and 3 have the values of Col2 and Col3 updated while Col4 remain with the same value.

[image: Update / Insert into the table on the second run of the SP.]
Probably I have to create a loop in the stored procedure where each row in the dataset returned by the SELECT statement is processed but I am new to stored procedures and I am having difficulties.  Code examples are much appreciated so I can understand better.

Thanks

Comment: Try reading up on `MERGE` - sounds like what you need. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: @user2307236 Some points that need clarification: (1) In Step 2, I'm assuming you meant Col4, not Col5. (2) In your walkthrough, you have a table with ID's {1,2,3,7} already existing, yet you say that you then want to **insert** {7}. Don't you mean you want to **update** 7? (3) What is going on with third table? Where did it come from? And why are most of the dates changed?

Comment: @Mike Solved using MERGE. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what do you mean by inserting data into table from select - Merge need source table from which you can update/insert/delete target.

try following if help

```
      MERGE tabelName WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS target
    USING (SELECT Column1, Column2,Column3,Column4) AS source (Column1, Column2,Column3,Column4)  // here goes your source 
    ON (target.Column1 = source.Column1)  
    WHEN MATCHED THEN   
        UPDATE SET Column2  = source.Column2, Column3 =source.Column3
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
    INSERT ( Column1, Column2,Column3,Column4)  
    VALUES ( source.Column1, source.Column2,source.Column3,source.Column4)  ;
```

Comment: Tks for your reply.  By 'INSERTING DATA INTO TABLE FROM SELECT' I mean the the source table is a SELECT statment from a table.

Comment: Solved using MERGE. Thanks